# Convert numeric values to alternative values in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two variables, `$audience` and `$prodType` that will hold value of 1-3 and 1-4 respectively. I'd like to build a table of sorts to convert the numeric values into words that a user can read and understand. For example, if `$audience = '1'` I would like the script to `Write-Host "audience is set to New York"` and if `$prodType = '3'`, the script would `Write-Host "prodType is set to Sandwiches"`.

I would like a cleaner way to do this then a series of `elseif` statements.

```bsh
If($audience = '1'){
  Write-Host "audience is set to New York"
}
elseif($audience = '2'){
  Write-Host "audience is set to Los Angeles"
}
```

Can anyone help me build such a module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of ways to achieve this, but based on your scenario the easiest is [with hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables):

```
$audienceLocation = @{
  '1' = 'New York'
  '2' = 'Berlin'
  '3' = 'Beijing' 
}

$audience = '1'

Write-Host "audience is set to $($audienceLocation[$audience])"
```

---

In your case the input values are all strings - but if they were numerical and you didn't mind converting to a string label without spaces, [an `enum` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum) would be an option as well.

Enums are just collections of string labels associated with some underlying integer, and can be converted in either direction with a simple cast:

```
enum AudienceLocation
{
  NewYork = 1
  Berlin  = 2
  Beijing = 3
}

$audience = 1
$location = [AudienceLocation]$audience

Write-Host "audience is set to $location"
```

The nice thing about an `enum` is that it's a proper type, so you can implicitly convert function input to a specific enum type parameter:

```
function Do-Something
{
  param([AudienceLocation]$Audience)

  Write-Host "audience is set to $Audience"
}

Do-Something -Audience 1 # will automatically turn `$Audience` into `'NewYork"` in a string
```

Comment: Ah the `@{}` is what i needed. Does that function have a name?

Comment: @Garrett That's a `[hashtable]` literal. Hash tables are basically unordered (and super-fast) dictionaries. Will update the answer with a link to documentation

Comment: I've never used `enum`, going to keep this thread for future reference, looks super helpful. Thanks for all the great info!